# scrollbar on left not working, exepcted scrollbar is like right one

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, scrollbar

i've two scrollbars here https://www.masalacode.com/python-for-loop/ one is on the left the short width one (wordpress site), it isn't working properly, I want it to work like the one on the extreme right, please assist.

thanks folks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update CSS on your website & add more menus into the sidebar.

```
#sfm-sidebar.sfm-compact .sfm-va-middle{
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

You can see video by run code.

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:53.750%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/e/3zx5fv" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>
```